# CiviCRM fetch_bounce scheduled job returning 'no database selected' error

Tags: wordpress, civicrm

I've been checking this for a while and not finding any answers.  I'm trying to run a fetch_bounces job in CiviCRM 4.6.1 on Wordpress 4.3 with the cli.php script as follows:

```
php public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -j -s *site* -u *username* -p *password* -e Job -a fetch_bounces
```

but I'm getting multiple lines that look like this as errors:

```
Failed Processing: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender, Action: b, Job ID: 339, Queue ID: 13323, Hash: 8b3263eb6a21bcf8. Reason: DB Error: no database selected
```

all have different Job IDs, Queue IDs, and hash values, but all have the same fail reason.  I've checked my civicdm.settings.php and the correct databases seem to be listed.  Any suggestions on what this could be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in the code, but it's also highly likely that it has been fixed, for two reasons.  First, we haven't seen this with our clients.  Second, version 4.6.1 had a very short lifespan, and there have been a number of releases since.  You should upgrade your site to the most recent 4.6.x version and try again.

Separately, you should check out the [CiviCRM StackExchange site](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com), which is where you'll find most questions and answers relating to CiviCRM.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Andrew.  Sorry for the confusion, we are on 4.6.10 (the latest) not 4.6.1.  Very strange, do you still think it could be a bug?  We're just running without those jobs for the time being.

Comment: In that case, I'm thinking the problem would be on your end. Could you try running it from the command line, getting the error, and immediately trying to access the site from the front end?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Andrew!